# Why does Windows make a sound when I press Alt+S?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, shortcuts

I can not figure this out for the life of me. I use alt + S to save and close tickets in ConnectWise but every-time I do it my PC makes a notification sound.

I've tried this in other applications as-well and it still makes the sound, it seems there is an in-built function in Windows for alt + s but I can't find anything online mentioning it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how the question got changed to ctrl+S, I definitely put Alt+S. I am trying to determine what Alt+S does not Ctrl+S

Comment: Even checked https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts and it's not listed at all, strange

Comment: Doesn't do it in Chrome or on the desktop but it does it within most applications, including notepad

Comment: ConnectWise is third-party software it’s keyboard shortcut will not appear in Microsoft documents.  Question body mentions ALT not CTRL.  CTRL+S typically is used to save a document, it is not a Windows shortcut, if it’s doing something other than you expect you have software installed that is using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's precisely because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> doesn't do anything in your active application that Windows makes the sound. By default, <kbd>Alt</kbd> toggles your menu options (i.e. if you're in Notepad and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it will underline your shortcut options for **F**ile, **E**dit, F**o**rmat, **V**iew, and **H**elp - so that if you press the shortcut for File (<kbd>F</kbd>) after pressing/holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it will open the File menu. If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Anything not assigned a shortcut in the active window</kbd>, Windows will make the noise you're hearing. Furthermore, <kbd>Alt</kbd> activates your ability to use those shortcuts (meaning you don't have to hold it the entire time) - so you could press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd> to open the File menu, then <kbd>S</kbd> to save a file in Notepad.

This is essentially what you have been doing in ConnectWise - <kbd>Alt</kbd> opens your menu and <kbd>S</kbd> is the Save shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I heard the sound while playing Rainbow Six, I solved it by looking at the volume mixer (right click on Sounds, Open Volume Mixer (idk if the translation is correct because my computer isn't in English). While pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> look at the app that makes the sound (you can figure it out by muting all the different apps sequentially).
In my case the app was Steelseries GG (for the mouse), by looking at the shortcuts I found <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> was associated with "Make Clips", just turn it off and your problem hopefully will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Home version 10.0.19043:

Perhaps resurrecting an old post, but you can find the exact system sound in "Change System Sounds" (can be found by searching through the quick-launch tray).

The sound you're hearing is "Default Beep" about six entries down. You can change this to a more pleasant sound by selecting it and using the dropdown menu below, or change it to no sound by selecting "(none)" from the list.

Make sure you apply before you close the window, and test your use case.